# Best practice to make 2 separate endpoints or throw all the data into 1 endpoint

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently getting the categories from woocommerce and I came upon this question. There are parent categories and child categories. Now I created 2 endpoints.

`getParentCategories` and `getCategoriesByParentId` to get the child categories.

I realized that I can also combine these two and make 1 endpoint out of it. Then you return the data like this:

```json
[
  {
    "category_name": "Shoes",
    "category_slug:  "/shoes",
    "child_categories":[
      {
          "category_name": "Sneakers",
          "category_slug:  "/sneakers",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What is best practice? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since you're asking for opinions, which is off topic for this site.

Comment: Hmm, I am asking for the best practice in general. This could help others make a better decision

Comment: So far you have two answers.. they are both opinions. I'd say that this question is seeking opinions. [ask]

Comment: All depends on the case. In some cases two is better in other one is better if you need the whole structure.

Comment: @HowardE Hmm okay true, on which site can I ask for opinions?

Comment: @MartinMirchev Ah okay, thanks for the answer. In this case, it is using a WordPress backend

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest maintaining them separately for separation of concern. If you are handling them separately then if something goes wrong with one of the them the other one won't be affected.

Comment: Hmm that's sounds smart

Answer (score 0):

My thought process is to try and keep your requests as small as possible.

Crazy idea:
Why not create a custom endpoint using the REST Api and return a json which contains the parent and child categories?

The benefit to me is that you will only use 1 request to fetch all the data + you have control of what is in the JSON (as you're the one who built the custom endpoint).

Comment: If I need to keep the requests as small as possible, then it is better to have 2 separate requests right? And your crazy idea is what I already mentioned in my question :D

Comment: oh crap I must have (forgot) to read your last part! :P

Comment: yeah with small I meant, less request to hit the rest api for data. But yeah you're idea is (in my opinion) the cleaner solution.

Comment: Hahaha no problem man. Ah, now I understand. Then I go with the 2 separate endpoints. thanks ;)